# Why can L'Hôpital's Rule be applied to $ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\ln x} $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\ln x}
$$
Surely L'Hôpital's Rule can't be applied here because $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0 \neq \lim_{x\to\infty}\ln x= \infty$ but the resource I am using says L'Hôpital's Rule does apply here.

Differentiating the numerator and denominator gets you $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{1}{x} = 0$ Is this just a coincidence?

Comment: You should start doubting that resource -- it seems to be giving you a right result for a wrong reason.

Comment: There’s not even the need of applying the rule here. Maybe there is a typo and the limit is for $x\to 0$…? That would make much more sense

Comment: Why do this? Since $x\log(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$, the limit is immediately clear.

Comment: So is the $x$ going to $0+$ or to infinity? If $x$ is going to infinity, then I don't see how L'Hospital even applies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know where this comes from so I can't say if there's a mistake or not. But it's no coincidence. L'Hospital's rule is applicable here. The version of the rule as stated in most textbooks says you need to have a limit of the form $$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$ A [more general version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form) of the rule applies to limits of the form $$\frac{\text{anything}}{\infty}$$ There's not even a requirement that the limit of the numerator exist! Of course, all other (often neglected) hypotheses of the rule still have to be satisfied.

Comment: "There's not even a requirement that the limit of the numerator exist!". So if the numerator is $tan(x^2)$ and the denominator is $x$ and the limit $x$ goes to infinity, does the fraction have a limit according to you? Would it be zero? I wouldn't stick my hand in the fire for such a statement...

Comment: @imranfat As I said, all other hypotheses of L'Hospital's rule have to be true. In your example $f(x)=\tan(x^2)/x$ isn't defined in any interval of the form $(a,\infty)$ so it's not even clear that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ makes sense.